# How get name of table Sphinx?

Tags: php, sphinx

I use PHP sphinx client(PECL):

```
$s = new SphinxClient; $s->setServer("localhost", 9312);
$s->setMaxQueryTime(9000);
$s->setMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_ANY);

$result = $s->query($_POST['search'], '*');
var_dump($result);
```

After request I get an output array:

```
 ["fields"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "type"
    [1]=>
    string(18) "specializationname"
    [2]=>
    string(17) "detailtousersname"
    [3]=>
    string(18) "detailtousersphoto"
  }
```

In output array I tried to get the name of table, where was found data(ID's). This setting I set at sphinx.conf:

```
sql_query = SELECT idArticle as id, 'article' as type...
sql_field_string  = type
```

How I can get a table name `'article'`?

The source **config** example:

```
source users : lsParentSource
{

    sql_query_range   = SELECT MIN(idDetailToUsers), MAX(idDetailToUsers) FROM detailtousers
    sql_range_step    = 128
    sql_query         = SELECT idDetailToUsers as id, 9 as type, UsersTypeAccount, idDetailToUsers, SpecializationName, DetailToUsersName, DetailToUsersPhoto, city, country FROM detailtousers join users ON users.idUsers = detailtousers.idDetailToUsers left join usersspecialization ON usersspecialization.UsersSpecializationIdUser = detailtousers.idDetailToUsers left join specializationtousers ON specializationtousers.idSpecialization = usersspecialization.UsersSpecializationIdSpecialization WHERE idDetailToUsers >= $start AND idDetailToUsers <= $end GROUP BY idDetailToUsers

    sql_attr_uint     = type
    sql_attr_uint     = idDetailToUsers
    sql_attr_uint     = UsersTypeAccount
    sql_field_string  = SpecializationName
    sql_field_string  = DetailToUsersName
    sql_field_string  = DetailToUsersPhoto
    sql_attr_uint     = city
    sql_attr_uint     = country

    sql_query_info    = SELECT idDetailToUsers, DetailToUsersName, UsersTypeAccount, SpecializationName, DetailToUsersPhoto, city, country \
                        FROM detailtousers WHERE idDetailToUsers = $id
    sql_ranged_throttle = 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The results array should contain a 'attrs' array in the matches array (one per document).

Comment: There is not `attr` array.  I added to question my source config

Comment: On one index 'type' is a string attribute, on the other its an int. It needs to match.